# How did the adult industry create an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, app-store

Quick question guys, I have been trying to figure out how Youporn has developed their iPhone app using a web shortcut.  PC world claims they did it with HTML 5 but how could they create the app without violating apples TOS...don't you need a apple Enterprise Dev account for this???

Comment: maybe they edit rating while upload app in appstore and make 18+ and contain nuditiy frequently. if we have predefined our app details then apple will not reject. not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am speculating without downloading it, but if PC World indicated that they used HTML 5, then quite simply, they are not on the App Store, they are running a progressive web application that looks and feels like a mobile application, including the ability to download things and function offline.

With all the advanced controls and capabilities of modern browsers (including on the iPhone), this is not really a surprise that they could do this. You can load any web URL as an app icon in your iPhone and have been able to from the beginning. If the URL loads a single page application that is designed to look and behave like a mobile application, that's how you'd do it.